# Unable to concat physical path of a file and file name in php

Tags: php

Here comes a problem when i about to concat the following

```
string 1 = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\packiya\new_iiser\assets\uploads\banner'

string 2 = '\'

string 3 = 'file_name.ext'
```

I was unable to concat these three strings.

Answer (score 1):

What problems are you facing? A simple concatination like this should work:

```
$concatenatedString = $string1.$string2.$string3
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple,for e.g

```
<?php
$a = "Hello ";
$b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

$a = "Hello ";
$a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```